# Run as spring boot app is not working where as run as java app working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build

I am using STS.

This is my main class:

```
    @EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication


    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(DevProxyApp.class, args);

        }catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Below is my build.gradle :

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'pmd'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.6.2'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

mainClassName = 'com.siemens.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp'
group = 'mindsphere'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'sdk-devproxy'
    doLast {

    }
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/libs/mindsphere/sdk-devproxy/$project.version/")
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-parent', version: 'Edgware.SR3', ext: 'pom'
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.3.0'
    compile('com.auth0:java-jwt')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

i have also tried with below dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '1.2.1.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-parent', version: 'Edgware.SR3', ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-oauth2', version: '1.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-zuul', version: '1.4.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.3.0'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Whenever I run the application as spring boot app its giving me the below error:

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class com.siemens.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp
```

While running as java application, it is working starting but with this kind of launch functionalities(oauth2, zuul routing functionalities) are not working.

i have tried below things, but still issue is there:

- Refreshing , rebuilding, updating gradle
- removing all the dependencies manually, removing gradle repo manually
- installed new STS.

If you need any other info to address this issue please let me know.

FYI Previously it was a maven project and working fine, now I am making it as gradle project by adding build.gradle, gradle project and etc. and removed pom.xml. Gradle build is happening properly.

Is the issue with any jar compatibility ????

Comment: I have the opposite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948998/in-eclipse-a-spring-boot-webflux-websocket-application-runs-correctly-as-gradle

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a manifest attribute:

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'com.siemens.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp'
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Still same issue I am getting

Comment: Where's Main class placed? You should put it at src/main/java/base.package if isn't. Also, just mainClassName: com.siemens.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp should work properly

Comment: Its proper ...Do you see the issue with jar compatibility ?

Comment: Hey issue was group id and package structure were not in synch. Its working fine now,... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the springBootVersion.
I had this issue and this resolved it.